# AWS Lambda track and limit authenticated calls from user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I currently have an S3 bucket running a static website with Cognito user authentication. I call a Lambda function from this bucket which validates the user's JWT token. I am trying to limit the number of calls the user is able to make to the function, such as 1 every hour. How would I go about doing this?

- My initial plan was to do something on the front-end, but that would easily bypassed.
- I looked to see if there was an AWS service for this, but the closest I found was Cloudtrail which doesn't really fit this
- My current plan is to create Cognito userAttributes to track how many calls the user has made and update them through lambda, but this also feels like the wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

There is no service from AWS for such a use case. You have to build something on your own.

Like I would change the architecture a bit:

Instead of calling the lambda directly, I would first put a lambda which will keep the counter for the user in a cache like ElastiCache. Depending on the outcome of this function whether to throttle or let it pass, I would execute actual lambda for validating the user's JWT token by using lambda destinations or add an event bus in between them to handle them more gracefully.

I accept there are some moving parts here, but this certainly makes things easier.

I see you directly serving from S3 try checking out the AWS API Gateway Service Integration more options there for authentication and validation including throttling. [For example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)